# How can I get the attribute value in different element source with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I'm new in Python Selenium I wanted to scrape the name and data-id in tr/td[2]/input and save into text file. Here this is the source

```html
<tr data-index="0">
  <td class="no-wrap" style="">David</td>
  <td class="no-wrap" style="">
    <input data-model="ns" data-model-field="ref_no" data-id="360823025057" type="text" class="form-control input-sm js-input-ref-no" maxlength="25"></td>
</tr>
```

This is my code but its din work

```
name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*tbody/tr/td[1]")
ID   = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*tbody/tr/td[2]/input")

with open('output.txt','a')as file:
     for i in range(len(name)):
         file.write(name[i].text + ";" + ID[i].get_attribute('data-id') + "\n")
file.close()
```

can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
tabledata = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*tbody/tr")
for table in tabledata:
    name = table.find_element_by_xpath("./td").text # The 1st `td`
    id = table.find_element_by_tag_name("input").get_attribute("data-id")
    print(name,id)
```

Comment: Yes ..i got it ... thank you so much pmadhu. Really appreciate